# SQL Server UDF Function needs to remove the numbers after the decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using the following Function to remove extra non numeric characters from the column.

```
ALTER Function [dbo].[fnRemoveNonNumericCharacters](@strText VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @strText = STUFF(@strText, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText), 1, '')
    END
    RETURN @strText
END
```

but if the value is  `99.35`, it is making it `9935`, but i want it to be `99`

Can anyone guide me what i am missing in the regex. and i am not sure if it covering up the spaces too or not

Comment: Just add `'.'` into the characters that are allowed.

Comment: u ean like this `[^0-9.]`

Comment: if i do like above, it just keeps the decimals as `99.35`

Comment: If it is to extract the value before `.`, why do you need that logic? Try `SELECT LEFT('99.35', 2)`

Comment: i had created a function because this function needs to be implemented in numbers of columns, so trying to remove that in the function itself

Comment: @GordonLinoff what if the text is multiple sentences such as "Today 90.9% of questions have been answered.  This trend is 2% behind normal."  The result would yeild 90.9.2.  Jack will this be a worry?  If so how do you want the result?  Are you attempting to create a mechanism to pass a string to convert to a number or for another reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not worried there will be multiple decimal points/periods. You can combine a few of the comments and John's answer like so:

```
ALTER Function [dbo].[fnRemoveNonNumericCharacters](@strText VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', @strText) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @strText = STUFF(@strText, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText), 1, '')
    END

    RETURN CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@strtext AS NUMERIC)) AS INT)
END
```

Comment: i need int, i had made a change to return me INT

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just replacing the non-numeric character that is going to be a `.` or a `,` or some other delimiter for numeric, just get the left from that point.

```
SET @strText = LEFT(@strText,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText) - 1)
```

EXAMPLES

```
DECLARE @strText VARCHAR(1000)

SET @strText = '98,255465465'
SET @strText = LEFT(@strText,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText) - 1)
SELECT @strText --98

SET @strText = '97.2554,65465'
SET @strText = LEFT(@strText,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText) - 1)
SELECT @strText --97

SET @strText = '982/554.65465'
SET @strText = LEFT(@strText,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText) - 1)
SELECT @strText --982
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @String varchar(1000) = '99.35'
Select floor(@String)
```

Returns 99